# Connect internet camera and bridge/forward IP traffic

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, bridge, bridge-router

I have an Ubuntu (14.04) machine with two Ethernet cards.
One Ethernet card (eth0) is connected to the office network.
The machine is addressable from the outside Internet. 
I have a Web camera that runs its own little Web server. The camera has an Ethernet NIC in it.

I want to connect the camera to the Ubuntu machine's second NIC (eth1) and set up some some kind of forwarding. The idea is to hit to reach the camera's Web server from the Internet and view images, etc. The camera can also upload its images to an FTP server, and I would like it to connect to an FTP server I have running on the Ubuntu machine.

I'm pretty sure I need to bridge the NICs by editing **/etc/network/interfaces** to look like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

This is where I get lost. Do I need to set up iptables to forward IP traffic arriving at the Ubuntu machine on some port (e.g. 51001) to port 80 on ... eth1 .... ? I can't visualize what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bridge the eth0 and eth1 interfaces. You need to set up Port Address Translation (PAT) in `iptables` to forward traffic to the webcam. See http://www.fclose.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/